# How to dynamically show a list of data by React?

Tags: reactjs, database, list, react-redux

I am new to `React` and trying to display list of data with `checkbox` and `inputbox`. In details, I want to grab a series of data from `database` and put each record into a `<div>` like `element` with `checkbox` and `inputbox`. So I can check the record and change the data and then do the re-save action after clicking a button. Since the number of data will keep changing, how to make it dynamic? Also, how can I mark down which records are being checked and need to be saved? Thanks!

Code:

```
App.js:
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Menu, Message, Button, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import SemanticDatepicker from 'react-semantic-ui-datepickers';
import 'react-semantic-ui-datepickers/dist/react-semantic-ui-datepickers.css';
import Form from './Form';

export default function App(props){
    const [currentDate, setNewDate] = useState(null);
  const onChange = (event, data) => setNewDate(data.value);
    const loadData= (event) => {
        return (<Form date = {currentDate} />);
    };
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div>
                <Menu borderless>
                    <Menu.Item >
                        <div >
                            <img src={logo} alt="image" />
                        </div>
                    </Menu.Item>
                </Menu> 
                
                <Segment>
                    <SemanticDatepicker onChange={onChange} />
                    <Button onClick={loadData}>Load Data</Button>
                </Segment>
                <Segment>>
                </Segment>
                //Here will diaplyed returned list of data after click button
            </div>
        </div> 
    )
};
```

Simple JSON response:

```
{
"APPLE":{
  "PRICE":100
},
"ORANGE":{
  "PRICE":20
},
"PEAR":{
  "PRICE":10
}
}
```

Comment: can you give some examples of a variety of data?

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá added the example above. The data will be in JSON format. So, I would like to display APPLE, ORANGE, PEAR in a list. So I can change the price of each record and check it and then save the checked records.

Comment: so, basically an input field to save the price, right?

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá Yes, the price will be show in the input field as default and you can correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your data to build your form.

1. You need to build the state from your data.
2. Also, map your `input` fields with respect to your state.
3. If the state needs different input fields, you could define your input fields in `deriveStateFromData`.

You can check the [example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-z3ex3n)

For `Object.keys`, you could check the [docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
import React from 'react';

const price = {
"APPLE":{
  "PRICE":100
},
"ORANGE":{
  "PRICE":20
},
"PEAR":{
  "PRICE":10
}
}

function deriveStateFromData(data) {
  let state = {}
  Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    state[key] = data[key]['PRICE']
  })
  return state;
}

function MyForm({ data }) {
  const [form, setFormData] = React.useState(deriveStateFromData(data));

  const handleChange = e => {
    setFormData({ ...form, [e.target.name]: Number(e.target.value) });
  }

  console.log(form)

  return (
    <>
      {Object.keys(form).map(key => {

        return (
          <div>
            <label>{key}</label>
            <input 
              name={key}
              value={form[key]}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}

const App = () => <MyForm data={price} />

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. but when I added the "return (<Form date = {currentDate} />);"  in the onClick function, there is nothing return. Am I missing something?

Comment: yeah, you're returning the Form from loadData and using it nowhere.

Comment: ic, how to return the form in the segment below button instead? Thanks

Comment: Check [this out](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ta7qtf)